# A Function doesn't work with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html, web

So the page loads, however a part of the page is fetched from the server, which loads up later, so I set up a setTimeout function, however after doing this the error comes up

`Uncaught reference error: check is not defined`

I also moved check function outside the `setTimeout` still no luck

When this is pasted without the timeout function in the developer console everything, the check function works fine.

```
setTimeout(function() {


    var getclass = document.getElementsByClassName('title');
    var containerlength = getclass.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < containerlength; i++) {
        var container = getclass[i];
        var jobid = getclass[i].children[0].innerHTML.trim().substring(0, 5);
        var fragment = document.createElement('div');
        var chk = "";
        if (localStorage.getItem(jobid) == 1) {
            chk = "checked";
            getclass[i].style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
        }
        fragment.innerHTML = '<input onclick="check(this)" class="jobs" value="' + jobid + '" name="' + jobid + '" type="checkbox"' + chk + '></input>';
        container.appendChild(fragment);

    }

    function check(ele) {
        //     alert(ele.name);
        var name = ele.name;
        var papa = ele.parentNode.parentNode;
        if (localStorage.getItem(name) == 1) {
            localStorage.setItem(name, 0);
            papa.style.textDecoration = 'none';
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem(name, 1);
            papa.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
        }
    }


}, 5000);
```

Comment: you should remove brace here.  ' fragment.innerHTML = '<input onclick="check(this){'

Comment: Sorry about that, I added it to the question here by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're trying to refer to a global `check` function, but not the local `check`.

With the current way you build the input element inside the loop you don't have access to the scope where `check` has been declared.

When you've access to the input element reference you can add/set event listeners to it – then the good thing here is to create the input element using [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), so that you have access to the returned HTML element reference in the same scope where you have access to `check`.

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.addEventListener('click', check.bind(null, input), false);
// This event listener could also be set
// through the 'HTMLElement#onclick' setter

fragment.appendChild(input);
```

Here's an example of implementation in your code: (I moved `check` to earlier's scope to free legibility)

```
var check;

check = function(ele) {
  var name = ele.name;
  var papa = ele.parentNode.parentNode;

  if (localStorage.getItem(name) === 1) {
    localStorage.setItem(name, 0);
    papa.style.textDecoration = 'none';

  } else {
    localStorage.setItem(name, 1);
    papa.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
  }
}

setTimeout(function() {
  var getclass = document.getElementsByClassName('title');
  var containerlength = getclass.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < containerlength; ++i) {
    var container = getclass[i];

    var jobid = getclass[i]
                  .children[0]
                  .innerHTML
                  .trim()
                  .substring(0, 5);

    var fragment = document.createElement('div');
    var chk = "";

    if (localStorage.getItem(jobid) === 1) {
      chk = "checked";
      getclass[i].style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
    }

    var input = document.createElement('input');

    input.addEventListener('click', check.bind(null, input), false);
    input.class = "jobs";
    input.value =
    input.name = jobid;
    input.type = "checkbox";

    fragment.appendChild(input);
    container.appendChild(fragment);

  }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I don't understand, could you elaborate your logic on codepen.com or something similar?

Comment: @SamFlynn Since I don't have base of your HTML page, I added an implementation example on the answer. Hope it be useful

Comment: Thanks this kind of solved the problem, except for the fact that the `line-through` still remains even after I uncheck the bex

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because you defined check function inside the scope of setTimeout callback. Try to get check function out of the scope, like this:

```
function check(ele)
{
    //     alert(ele.name);
    var name = ele.name;
    var papa = ele.parentNode.parentNode;
    if(localStorage.getItem(name) == 1)
    {
        localStorage.setItem(name, 0);
        papa.style.textDecoration = 'none';
    }
    else
    {
        localStorage.setItem(name, 1);
        papa.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
    }
}


setTimeout(function(){ 

var getclass = document.getElementsByClassName('title');
var containerlength = getclass.length;

for(var i=0; i<containerlength; i++)
{
    var container = getclass[i];
    var jobid = getclass[i].children[0].innerHTML.trim().substring(0, 5);
    var fragment = document.createElement('div');
    var chk = "";
    if(localStorage.getItem(jobid) == 1)
    {
        chk = "checked";
        getclass[i].style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
    }
    fragment.innerHTML = '<input onclick="check(this)" class="jobs" value="' + jobid + '" name="' + jobid + '" type="checkbox"' + chk + '></input>';
    container.appendChild(fragment);

}
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I see that answer from @Someone works for you, however if you want to use your shorter notation, you can try to use container.append() instead of container.appendChild(). appendChild() is a DOM function where append() is from jQuery. You can put something like this:  `container.append('<input onclick="check(this)" class="jobs" value="' + jobid + '" name="' + jobid + '" type="checkbox"' + chk + '/>');`

Comment: @MarekKoziorowski not exactly, if you want to pass the `check` function (declared before) to click event, you need to have access to that jQuery instance reference: `$(container).append($('<input>').click(() => check(this)))`

Comment: Ok, you got me.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the check function out side the timeout.By this your problem may be solved because the function will available always.

Comment: I edited the question, I did this too, it still doesn't work

Comment: you should remove brace.  fragment.innerHTML = '<input onclick="check(this){            if your are not mistakenly added in question

Comment: I had mistakenly done that in the question, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the check function outside of the setTimeout and remove the brace on your input.

Check this plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/sop3R4PqQ13M7DwovdnZ?p=preview

```
function check(ele) {
        //     alert(ele.name);
        var name = ele.name;
        var papa = ele.parentNode.parentNode;
        if (localStorage.getItem(name) == 1) {
            localStorage.setItem(name, 0);
            papa.style.textDecoration = 'none';
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem(name, 1);
            papa.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
        }
    }

setTimeout(function() {

    var getclass = document.getElementsByClassName('title');
    var containerlength = getclass.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < containerlength; i++) {
        var container = getclass[i];
        var jobid = getclass[i].children[0].innerHTML.trim().substring(0, 5);
        var fragment = document.createElement('div');
        var chk = "";
        if (localStorage.getItem(jobid) == 1) {
            chk = "checked";
            getclass[i].style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
        }
        fragment.innerHTML = '<input onclick="check(this)" class="jobs" value="' + jobid + '" name="' + jobid + '" type="checkbox"' + chk + '></input>';
    container.appendChild(fragment);

    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Yeah plunker is working but its not working on the website. Could it be a browser issue (chrome) or could it be a tampermonkey issue?